# Change background color on li:visited

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a tab page for which I want to apply a different background color when a tab was visited. How can I do that?

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
       <li><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pane">
    <div id="tab1">
        <p>This is first tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <p>This is second tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" style="display:none;">
        <p>This is third tab</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.tabs>li {float: left; padding: 10px; background-color: lightgray;
          margin-right:5px; border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
      }

ul.tabs li a{text-decoration:none;}

ul.tabs li a:visited{color:red;}

ul.tabs li:visited{background:lime;}

p{padding:40px;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
        $(".pane div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uFALn/63/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML element `li` does not have a `:visited` selector. You need to apply all your CSS to the anchor.

Change the `ul.tabs>li` to `ul.tabs a` and set the background for

```
ul.tabs li a:visited {
    color:red;
    background: lime;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFALn/72/) for working code.

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
        $(".pane div").hide();
        $(this).parent().addClass('visited')
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
})​
```

and css for it:

```
ul.tabs li.visited{
background:lime;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uFALn/67/)

`:visited` is applied to references only. At the same time -code above will not work after page reload (as it should be for links). You may additionally test links color on document.ready and set corresponding class on `LI`s

Another option: form tab headers with links, not with `LI`s (main css changes):

```
ul.tabs>li {
     float: left;

}
ul.tabs>li a {
    padding: 10px;
          display:block;
          background-color: lightgray;
          margin-right:5px;
          border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
      }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uFALn/75/)

Answer (score 2):

The `visited` pseudo-class won't work on `li`s, because they're not links and there's no way to "visit" a li element.

So, what you can do is to set `a`s to `display:block;` and give **them** the background color.

This will work even ***after*** page change/refreshes.

Your new CSS:

```
ul.tabs>li {
    float: left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

ul.tabs li a { /* padding, background and border-radius goes here now */
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}

ul.tabs li a:visited{color:red;}

ul.tabs li a:visited { /* li a:visited instead of li:visited */
    background:lime;
}

p{padding:40​px;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/KHSZ8/)**

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pane">
<div id="tab1">
    <p>This is first tab</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
    <p>This is second tab</p>
</div>
<div id="tab3" style="display:none;">
    <p>This is third tab</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul.tabs>li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;

  margin-right:5px;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
li{
background: lightgray;
}
ul.tabs li a{
text-decoration:none;
}

ul.tabs li a:visited{
color:red;
}

ul.tabs li:visited{
background:lime;
}

p{
padding:40px;
}

.active{
    background:blue;
}
​
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(".pane div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
})​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/uFALn/78/)